# Mock Play JDBC connection in ScalaTest test

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, scalatest

I have the following Play for Scala Controller that injects a JDBC connection:

```
class MyController @Inject() (db1: play.api.db.Database) extends Controller  {
    // some code
}
```

In my `application.conf` I have the related configuration:

```
# JDBC configuration
  db.default.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
  db.default.url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db0001"
  db.default.username=root
  db.default.password=xxxxxxx
```

Now, what I need is to inject in a ScalaTest test a different database (also defined in `application.conf`). Should be declared in the test as follows:

```
val controller = new MyController (mockDB)
```

How can this be achieved?

Comment: You can have a look at http://acolyte.eu.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare it like this:

```
    val mockDB = Databases(
      driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver",
      url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/db0001"
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 val config  : Config = ConfigFactory.parseString(
    """test-db {
      |  driver = "slick.driver.H2Driver$"
      |  db = {
      |    driver = "org.h2.Driver"
      |    url = "jdbc:h2:mem:testDB"
      |  }
      |}
      |""".stripMargin)
  val dbConfig: DatabaseConfig[JdbcProfile] = DatabaseConfig.forConfig[JdbcProfile]("test-db", config)
val db = dbConfig.db

lazy val app = new GuiceApplicationBuilder()
    .overrides(bind[Database].toInstance(db))
    .build
```

Answer (score 0):

you should ask yourself:

1. Do you need to run real queries in a database?
2. Would mocking the DB suffice?

If your answer to #2 is "yes", you may use ScalaMock

```
class Test extends MockFactory {
   val mockDB = mock[DatabaseConfig[JdbcProfile]]
   (mockDb.db.run _) expects(*) returning(/*The value you want to return goes here*/)
    val controller = new MyController(mockDB)
}
```

[ScalaMock Official Site](https://scalamock.org/)